# How to access pipeline identifier in azure devops resource triggered pipeline inside a template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have Azure DevOps yaml deployment pipelines that trigger when a build pipeline completes and publishes an artifact.  According to [docs found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#download-for-pipelines), artifacts will be downloaded to

> to $(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/pipeline-identifier/artifact-identifier folder.

my trigger is similar to

```
resources:
 pipelines:
 - pipeline: SmartHotel-PipelineIdentifier
   project: DevOpsProject
   source: SmartHotel-CI
   trigger:
     branches:
      include:
      - main
```

How can i access the pipeline-identifier from a template?  I need to be able to create

> $(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/SmartHotel-PipelineIdentifier/artifact-identifier

based upon the pipeline definition above.

When the pipeline is triggered by a build, I'm able to use

> $(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(resources.triggeringAlias)/artifact-identifier

to give me what I need, but that value is blank when the pipeline is triggered manually.

How can I access what appears to be called the pipeline-identifier value for a specific pipeline to be used within templates in the deployment jobs of pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

You can get various [properties of the pipeline resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline-resource-variables), but that's all assuming you know the alias. But there's no way to get that alias if it's not triggered automatically. If you had more pipeline resources, how would you know which one to get?

In this case, you could:

- pass the pipeline identifier (`SmartHotel-PipelineIdentifier`) as a parameter to the template.
- assume a convention for well-known pipeline identifiers (i.e. always use `artifact-pipeline` instead of `SmartHotel-PipelineIdentifier`)
- download (or move) the artifact to a well-known location before calling the template. That's assuming you already use the pipeline identifier for the `download` task anyway, so you could simply do `mv $(Pipeline.Workspace)/SmartHotel-PipelineIdentifier/artifact-identifier $(Pipeline.Workspace)/artifact-identifier` right after download.

  You can also use the full [DownloadPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#download-artifacts-from-a-specific-projectpipeline) task (which `download` is a shorthand for) and configure it to download to a different directory.
- determine the directory name in runtime, once the artifact is downloaded and set a pipeline variable dynamically:

  ```yaml
    # there will be directories in $(Pipeline.Workspace) like "a", "b", "s" for checked out repositories - ignore them
  - pwsh: |
      ls $(Pipeline.Workspace)
      $alias = Get-ChildItem $(Pipeline.Workspace) | ? { $_.Name.Length -gt 1 } | select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ArtifactAlias]$alias"
    displayName: determine artifact pipeline alias
  - pwsh: echo 'alias: $(ArtifactAlias)' # use $(ArtifactAlias) where you would use $(resources.triggeringAlias)
  ```

Comment: thank you for your response.  I'm currently setting a variable in each resource pipeline and using that variable in the template.  I posted here in hopes that Azure DevOps people would point me to the built-in variable that should exist.  I am using the download task as it is much faster and works better than the "task" version.  The only problem is that it writes to a folder named for the "alias" or "pipeline-identifier" or other names in the docs, and I need to dynamically know this as I have many microservices being deployed to same vm & am leveraging templates.

Comment: I added another option, hope this one will be useful to you.